# Why a Textbox.MaximumSize value is changed at compilation time?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, height

I have a usercontrol with a Textbox inside.
I need that textbox with MaximumSize of 267,0.
For some reason if I compile the project that value is setted to 267,4. That breaks a code that i use to resize its height size in response to text editions.
Somebody has face this problem before? What can be the reason?

Comment: That 4 in height could be nonclient area of `TextBox` (to draw borders with shadow). Try to avoid layouting or sizing this way. In winforms you can use `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Try disabling the `AutoSize` property on the `TextBox`: `textBox1.AutoSize = false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set ***TextBox.AutoSize*** to ***'false'*** (you won't see it in Properties window, intelisence won't show it, but it's there). Otherwise the TextBox will just keep ignoring the Height part of the MaximumSize.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons for the resize. Two I can think of:

Try disabling the [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
textBox1.AutoSize = false;
textBox1.Height = 0;
```

Check the anchors. If you have the `TextBox` anchored to the top and bottom of its container *(i.e. the user control)*, and that container is resized, then the `TextBox` will be resized as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `TextBox.MaximumSize` is 267,0 at design time, it seems that `TextBox.Border` influences the runtime values as follows:

If **None**, the `TextBox.MaximumSize` is 267,0.
If **FixedSingle**, the `TextBox.MaximumSize` is 267,2.
If **Fixed3D**, the `TextBox.MaximumSize` is 267,4.